# Different AIC values for the same SARIMA model in different R packages

Tags: time-series, aic

I've been trying to run a simple time series model for a data set. My biggest question is when I run the [`auto.arima`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/auto.arima) model (from package "forecast) for this data set I receive an output as follows

```
mod1 <- auto.arima(datSet)
> mod1
Series: datSet 
ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,1)[12]                    

Coefficients:
         ma1    sma1
      0.5490  0.1047
s.e.  0.0506  0.0650

sigma^2 estimated as 42245:  log likelihood=-1693.13
AIC=3392.26   AICc=3392.36   BIC=3402.84
```

I interpret the AIC value as being 3392.26, but my problem arrives when I assign the model through the [`sarima`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/astsa/docs/sarima) function (from package "astsa"):

```
mod2 <- sarima(datSet, p = 0, d = 1, q = 1, P = 0, D = 0, Q = 1, S = 12)
mod2$AIC    
    > mod2$AIC
[1] 11.67195
```

Unless I am doing/interpreting something wrong, I'm assuming both models would have been the same; so why is there such a drastic difference in the AIC values and which would I use in my time series analysis?

Comment: In general, be careful comparing the AIC value between software packages as they may treat the constant term differently, and then the AIC values are not comparable. This is the most likely explanation here.

Comment: Also, some packages normalize the AIC by dividing it by the number of observations. This might be the case here. The [help file](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/astsa/docs/sarima) for `sarima` points to Shumway & Stoffer's textbook ([freely downloadable](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/)), Chapter 2, where we see that they define AIC using the normalization mentioned above.